# Explicitly define Camel Routes in Quarkus

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

**Current behaviour**: When I'm running a Quarkus App with Camel it automatically starts all the RouteBuilder Extensions as Routes.

**What I want to achieve**: On startup only the Routes that I configured are started.

**What I tried**:

1. With the following snippet it's possible to explicitly start the CamelMainApplication but I dont know how to get control over e.g. the CamelContext at this point where I would be able to configure my routes.

```
@QuarkusMain
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Quarkus.run(CamelMainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

2. On the Route I can use *.noAutoStartup()* to disable the route on startup. But this means that it's not the default for all routes to be disabled at first and second I don't know where to activate them as I don't know where in a Quarkus App I can get a hand on the Camel Context to activate the route.
3. With the following in my *application.yml* I can disable the automatic route discovery but then the remaining question is how I can manually start the route, e.g. in my *QuarkusMain* class.

```
quarkus:
 camel:
   routes-discovery:
     enabled: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is best way. Quarkus has properties for include and exclude route as pattern. this properties is List You can add one to N

```
quarkus.camel.routes-discovery.exclude-patterns=tes.Comp,tes.package.MyRoute
quarkus.camel.routes-discovery.include-patterns=test.mypackage.XX
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem I ended up doing something like the following:

```
@QuarkusMain
public class Main implements QuarkusApplication {

   @Inject
   OrderService orderService;

    @Override
    public int run(String... args) throws Exception {
        CamelRuntime runtime = Arc.container().instance(CamelRuntime.class).get();
        runtime.start(new String[]{});

        orderService.handleOrders(args[0]); //this would inject the camelContext and start the route. 


        return 0;
    }
```